# Is VMware's vmtar utility open-source?

Tags: vmware-esxi, automated-install

So I've bumped up against some `.vgz` archives in VMware ESXi 4.1, which I've gathered to be specialized gzipped tar archives.  [This post has some info](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/217233). These files can be manipulated using the `/sbin/vmtar` program in the ESXi scripted installer. I wondering:

A) Is this open source?  If so where can I find information on it?

B) If not, are there any freely available alternative Linux (or Solaris) implementations of vmtar?

Came up short on google. Hoping someone on serverfault knows.  My guess is this is a proprietary tool developed by VMware that is not otherwise available, but I figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 1):

IT might be open source, you can download all [ESX 4 Open Source Code](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_vsphere_4/4#open_source)

Comment: Well, I downloaded everything for ESXi Installable, which is a bunch of tarballs with src rpms, and I couldn't find it.  Mystery remains for now.

Comment: Apparently, as of March 2012 (probably even earlier), the link to "ESX 4.0 Open Source Code" is now in a slightly different location. The new URL is http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_cloud_infrastructure/vmware_vsphere/4_0#open_source